# How can I fix ElementaryOS not installing on a MacBook Air(2018) Intel

Tags: macbook, install, error

I am having problems with installing EOS on a 2018 MacBook air, it gives the error messages:
ACPI Error: Aborting Method.
ACPI BIOS error
Thunderbolt:ICM firmware is in wrong mode
xHCI Host controller not responding, assume dead.

Comment: Try this: Start the computer with the USB in the drive, boot to said USB, and press the enter button as soon as you've started this process. Done properly, a black screen will appear with some text about trying eOS. At that screen, press the tab button. Then, at the end of the text that appears, type in a space and then `noapic` and press the enter button to continue booting. As you're using a Mac, you may also need to add `nomodeset` to that same section. Report back if it works.

Comment: I have tried it, it responded with the same error code. I have tried installing eOS with the same USB on other computers and it worked, I wonder if it's a T2 chip problem.

Comment: It may be. Is that the 'new' in-house Apple CPU? If so, I don't know if any Linux distros are ready to work on it.

Comment: The T2 is the security chip, i think it stops thunderbolt starts on boot, I have an intel chip

Comment: Is there something like a 'disable secure boot' in your BIOS? (I don't do Apple hardware, so this is definitely out of my wheelhouse.)